# convert from year & day of year to date in bash

Tags: macos, shell, time

I have a table with two columns: year and day of year. I would like to covert them to dates (year-month-day)

The following command seems to read properly only the year but not the day of the year:

```
date -j -f "%Y %j" "2005 241" +%F
2005-02-03
```

I use bash on an OS X. Any advise?

**Solution**

```
$ yyyy="2015"; doy="241"; echo $(date -jf %s $(($(date -jf "%F %T" "$yyyy-01-01 23:59:30" +%s) + ((10#$doy - 1)) * 86400)) +"%F %T")
2015-08-29 23:59:30
$ date -j 082923592015 +%j
241
```

So basically, we take the given year and construct the time for the first day of that year (i.e., Jan 01) and transform it to seconds. Then, we add the total number of seconds since first day of the year (Careful here! we have to subtract one since the counting refers to Jan 01). The resulted summation expressed in seconds is finally converted to the expected format.

- *-j* does not set the date
- *-f* allow to specify the input format
- *+* allow to specify the output format
- *%s* seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
- *%F* date format same as %Y-%m-%d
- *%T* time format same as %H:%M:%S
- *%j* day of year as 3-digit number (e.g., 001 ... 366)
- *$(())* set the arithmetic context
- *10#.* convert the number to base 10 in order to avoid issues with leading zeros for the day of the year (e.g., 009, 099)

Answer (score 2):

By using Mac OS date, I've successfully run:

```
date -j -f %s $(($(date -j 0101012015 +%s)+241*86400)) +%F
2015-08-30
```

```
date -j -f %s $(date -j -f %F 2015-01-01 +%s+241*86400 | bc) +%F
2015-08-30
```

Where, by using GNU date v8.13 I use:

```
date -d "2005-1-1 +241 days" +%F
2005-08-30
```

Comment: @Inian I've added a way of doing this under Mac's bash

Comment: @Hauri: If you run the reverse command in GNU
`date -d 20150830 +%j`
the answer is 242 instead of 241. Therefore, one needs to subtract one day 
`date -d "2005-1-1 +240 days" +%F`
as the counting starts already from Jan 01.

Comment: @AjanO, I agree with you and hence something like `date -d "$1-01-01 +$2 days -1 day" "+%Y%m%d"` is appreciated.